# Does anyone know how to write this Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex pattern to match a string which might include (`) not ('). For example: "This is Joe`s book", which is different from "This is Joe's book". I know how to match a string with (') but (`). So does anyone know how to write this Regular Expression?

Thanks!

Comment: A) What language are you using regular expressions in - each language has a different set of supported features.  B) if you were able to give some example strings and wether or not they should match - it may help us

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
^[^']+$
```

The caret inside a bracket expression `[^ ]` is the negation operator.

Answer (score 1):

This captures strings from start `^` to end `$` containing the character range in the square brackets. Note the back-tick at the end of the range.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 \.,;:\?\!`]+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[^']*[`][^']*
```

Accept any number of characters (including 0) that are not a single quote until a you encounter a backtick, and then accept any characters (including 0) that are not a single quote after that

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting to test that the string has a back-tick:

```
/`/
```

Should work...

If you want to test for strings with backticks that don't contain apostrophes:

```
/^(?!.*').*`/
```

Should work...

Comment: Is there a regex pattern which can match all different symbol? such as: ',;-?$`&